# Can't send file via HttpPost multipart to sendgrid API

Tags: android, http-post, sendgrid

I've been stuck on this issue for a while. So I use SendGrid for send email and everything is ok except attach image file, So I follow the documentation from [this](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/mail.html)

and this is my code

```
    private class SendDataInBackGround extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Constants.MAIL_URL);

        try {
            MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity();
            multipartEntity.addPart("api_user", new StringBody(Constants.MAIL_USERNAME));
            multipartEntity.addPart("api_key", new StringBody(Constants.MAIL_PASSWORD));
            multipartEntity.addPart("to", new StringBody("me@mycompany.com"));
            multipartEntity.addPart("subject", new StringBody("subject"));
            multipartEntity.addPart("text", new StringBody("message"));
            multipartEntity.addPart("from", new StringBody("someone@somewhere.com"));

            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/safe.png");
            try {
                file.createNewFile();

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            multipartEntity.addPart("files", new FileBody(file));

            httppost.setEntity(multipartEntity);
            String res = httpclient.execute(httppost, new UploadResponseHandler());
            return res;
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
         Helper.createToast(getSherlockActivity(), result).show();
    }

    private class UploadResponseHandler implements ResponseHandler<String> {

        @Override
        public String handleResponse(HttpResponse response)
                throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

            HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();
            String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
            return responseString;
        }

    }
}
```

I'm not sure there's something I missed or have better solution for handle this.

Thanks.

Comment: do you have read external storage permission??

Comment: @IllegalArgument yes I have.

Comment: What does file.createNewFile do?

Comment: @greenapps just create mock up file to upload

Comment: What is `mock up`? For what do you need it?

Comment: no needed, So I removed that code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code that I am using and is working for me:

```
public void testUpload(String path,String url) {
    HttpResponse response;
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    try {
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        File f = new File(path);
        FileBody b = new FileBody(f);
        HttpEntity reqEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
                .addPart("ImageFile", b).build();
        reqEntity.getContentType().toString();
        httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
        if (resEntity != null) {
            System.out.println("Response content length: "
                    + resEntity.getContentLength());
        }
        Log.d("response", EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // httpclient.close();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Its basically the same I use this method to send multiple files to my server. Hope it helps you and as your and my method are similar it doesnot require any explanation but feel free to ask.